# In R, create 2D plot (two axes and values) from data frame

Tags: r

Below is an example of the question I have:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
y <- c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c')
z <- c(2.5, 4.5, 6.5, 5.0, 3.0, 7.5, 1.0, 6.5, 2.0)

fun <- data.frame(
  x = x,
  y = y,
  z = z
)
```

Now I have created the following data frame called `fun`:

```
  x y   z
1 1 a 2.5
2 1 b 4.5
3 1 c 6.5
4 2 a 5.0
5 2 b 3.0
6 2 c 7.5
7 3 a 1.0
8 3 b 6.5
9 3 c 2.0
```

Now, I want to create a 2D plot with x-axis being (1,2,3), y-axis being (a,b,c), and the values (colors) being the values of column `z`.

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice in base graphics

```
fun <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  y = c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c'),
  z = c(2.5, 4.5, 6.5, 5.0, 3.0, 7.5, 1.0, 6.5, 2.0)
)


zz <- with(fun, (z - min(z)) / diff(range(z)) * 998) + 1
par(mar = c(5,4,4,4))
with(fun, plot(x, y, pch = 19, cex = 2,
               col = colorRampPalette(c('black','blue','lightblue'))(1000)[zz]))

## adding a color bar
plotr::color.bar(c('black','blue','lightblue'),
                 at.x = par('usr')[4] * 1.05, at.y = par('usr')[3])
with(fun, text(x = par('usr')[2] * 1.06, y = pretty(1:3), xpd = NA, pos = 4,
               labels = pretty(fun$z, 3)))
```

[image]

or grid

```
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(data = fun, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = z)) + geom_point(size = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I didn't realize ggplot has such a straightforward function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @xiaoxiao87 yes it's nice for automatic legends, especially the color bar. doing that in base requires some extra work, see edit. there are third party packages that that a color bar function, plotrix has one I think